# Tizen Wearable - stress data in .Net

Tags: .net, xamarin, tizen

I am trying to access the stress levels data in a Tizen .Net app.

The web app documentation has it:
https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/sensors/human-activity-monitor#monitoring-stress

As @SushiHangover points out it can be accessed in the native API.  The documentation for this is at:
https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/4.0.0/org.tizen.native.wearable.apireference/group__CAPI__SYSTEM__SENSOR__LISTENER__MODULE.html

However it is not in the .Net documentation:
https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/.net-application/location-and-sensors/device-sensors 
https://samsung.github.io/TizenFX/API4/api/Tizen.Sensor.html

I understood that all native APIs were exposed in the Tizen .Net platform.  How to I get my hands on those stress data readings?

The app is for Galaxy Watch, which uses Tizen API 4.

Thank you!

Comment: The Human Activity Monitor APIs are for the "Web API" (JavaScript), there is no equivalent for Native (and thus .Net as it wraps the native apis) Tizen. Since you have access to the continous sensor data (via native|Net) you could implement the equivalent output.

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover, if you can provide an example of how to get stress data from the continuous sensor data, I'll be happy to mark as answer.

Comment: @SushiHangover I have updated the question, linking to the native API sensor page, but pointing out I can't find the .Net equivalent.  Hope you can direct me!

Answer (score 0):

Tizen API 4 does not provide access to the Stress sensors. There is not much You can do about it.
API level 6 will include Tizen.Sensor.StressMonitor class. You can check the [Pull Request 827](https://github.com/Samsung/TizenFX/pull/827) adding this feature.